# Как правильно откатиться до коммита и залить это на удаленный репозиторий?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote, git-push

Есть два репозитория:

1. голый (bare) репозиторий, из него все берут копию, в нем есть  мастер ветка, которая всегда соответствует production состоянию
2. есть локальный репозиторий

Разработчик откатывается к предыдущем коммиту в локальном репозитории `git reset --soft`, потом делает коммит, потом пуш.

Пуш отклоняется, разработчик делает пул и мержит локальный мастер и с удаленным, после чего отмененные строки кода опять встают на место и смысл затеи теряется!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно откатиться до коммита и залить это на удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: Воспользутейсь [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html) и откатите все лишние коммиты.

Comment: Как вариант `git push --force`. Только не злоупотребляйте.

Comment: ![](http://i.imgur.com/FpAdsW1.jpg?1)

Comment: Кот, все хорошо, но вот ситуация, произошел мердж, после этого один коммит, пытаюсь откатить последнее изменение к состояние до мерджа, пишет, что нужно git revert -m 

Попробовал и так, и сяк, но что-то ничего толком не вышло... 

Может был опыт такой?

Спасибо за ответы еще раз! =)

Comment: Стойте, вы сделали локальный merge, после этого какой-то коммит сверху и хотите отменить этот локальный коммит? Тогда используйте [`git reset --hard HEAD~1`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). Рекомендую сразу разобраться, как работают остальные опции команды `reset` (то есть, `--soft` и дефолтная опция `--mixed`).

Answer (score 5):

Для простоты предположим, что проблемный коммит только один.

Чтобы откатить опубликованный (push) коммит, есть два основных пути:

1. `git revert номер_проблемного_коммита`. Создаёт второй, "противоположный" коммит, "со знаком минус". После его публикации получится состояние, как до проблемного коммита, но в истории останется пара ненужный-коммит + отмена-ненужного-коммита.
2. `git push --force`. Перед этим нужен `git reset`, как советуют в комментариях. Эту опцию следует использовать с осторожностью. Рассмотрим следующие случаи:

   1. Никто ещё не увидел опубликовынные изменения (в том числе "роботы", которые могут что-то автоматически делать при push'е). Тогда `--force` наилучший вариант.
   2. Несколько человек уже обновились после неудачного коммита. Тогда перед использованием `--force` следует их уведомить, так как на их стороне `--force` может "взбаламутить" ситуацию и потребовать дополнительных действий. Если тут же вместо проблемного коммита не положить ещё какой-нибудь другой коммит, то проблемный коммит может снова попасть на сервер (даже без `--force`'а) от этих разработчиков.
   3. Кто-то уже опубликовал изменения поверх неудачного коммита. Тогда `--force` затрёт их новые коммиты. От этого можно защититься опцией `--force-with-lease`. В этом случае нужно обновиться и делать `git rebase -i`, а потом уже `--force` (причём во время этой операции могут набежать ещё новые коммиты). Тут `git revert` будет более уместен.
   4. Много человек уже обновилось, есть несколько опубликованных или неопубликованных изменений "поверх" плохого коммита: `git revert`.

Comment: Подробнее об откате коммитов: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472)

Answer (score 2):

как вариант

`git reflog` - выдаст список HEAD c номерами и описанием, достаточно выбрать интересуещее вас состояние и сделать сброс до этого HEAD.

`git reset --hard HEAD @{`номер`}`

> HEAD – это указатель на текущую ветку, которая, в свою очередь,
>   является указателем на последний коммит, сделанный в этой ветке. Это
>   значит, что HEAD будет родителем следующего созданного коммита. Как
>   правило, самое простое считать HEAD снимком вашего последнего коммита.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от платформы, Вы можете написать так:

**GitHub**

откат на 1 коммит локально:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

> Примечание: [это потенциально опасная команда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530204/8370915), так как она
>   сбрасывает все ваши незафиксированные изменения.

Потом удаляете в репозитории удаленно командой:

```
git push origin -f
```

---

По аналогии на **BitBucket**

откат на 1 коммит локально:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

и удаленно командой удаляете:

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

> Примечание: вместо ветки `master` Вы можете использовать любую другую
>   ветку. Этой командой Вы только удаляете с Bitbucket.

`HEAD~1` и `HEAD^` могут быть [взаимозаменяемыми](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git/1338744#comment1174894_1338744).