# Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert

Я хочу вернуться к более раннему коммиту. Как мне это сделать?

Вот что показывает команда `git log`:

```
$ git log
commit dddddd
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 18:59:41 2010 -0400

Add buzz

commit cccccc
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 05:13:39 2010 -0400

Add fizz

commit bbbbbb
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 00:55:06 2010 -0400

Add bar

commit aaaaaa
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 3 23:56:08 2010 -0400

Add foo
```

Comment: См. также: [Убрать последний git-коммит, не меняя файлов проекта](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533115/181472)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Этот вопрос можно понять по-разному:

1. Что значит вернуться или откатиться: просто посмотреть, изменить содержимое рабочей области, изменить историю Git?
2. Что именно откатить: рабочую область (worktree), индекс (область подготовки коммита, staging area), текущую ветку, удаленную ветку?
3. К какой позиции откатить: к индексу, к последнему коммиту, к произвольному коммиту?

Обозначим начальную ситуацию на следующей схеме:

```
               (i) (wt)
A - B - C - D - ? - ?
            ↑
          master
          (HEAD)
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` — коммиты в ветке `master`.
`(HEAD)` — местоположение указателя HEAD.
`(i)` — состояние индекса Git. Если совпадает c `(HEAD)` - пуст. Если нет - содержит изменения, подготовленные к следующему коммиту.
`(wt)` — состояние рабочей области проекта (working tree). Если совпадает с `(i)` — нет неиндексированных изменений, если не совпадает — есть изменения.
`↑` обозначает коммит, на который указывает определенная ветка или указатель.

Вот решения, в зависимости от задачи:

## 1. Временно переключиться на другой коммит

Если вам нужно просто переключиться на другой коммит, чтобы, например, посмотреть на его содержимое, достаточно команды [`git checkout`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-checkout/info):

```
git checkout aaaaaa

 (wt)
 (i)
  A - B - C - D
  ↑           ↑
(HEAD)    master
```

Сейчас репозиторий находится в состоянии «detached HEAD». Чтобы переключиться обратно, используйте имя ветки (например, `master`):

```
git checkout master
```

## 2. Переключиться на коммит и продолжить работу с него

Если вы хотите продолжить работу с другого коммита, вам понадобится новая ветка. Можно переключиться и создать ее одной командой:

```
git checkout -b имя-новой-ветки aaaaaa

 (wt)
 (i)
  A - B - C - D
  ↑           ↑
 new       master
(HEAD)
```

## 3. Удалить изменения в рабочей области и вернуть ее к состоянию как при последнем коммите.

Начальное состояние:

```
               (i) (wt)
A - B - C - D - ? - ?
            ↑
          master
          (HEAD)
```

### 3.1 Безопасно — с помощью кармана (stash)

#### 3.1.1 Только неиндексированные

Можно <s>удалить</s> прикарманить только те изменения, которые еще не были индексированы (командой `add`):

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

Конечное состояние:

```
               (wt)
               (i)       
A - B - C - D - ?         ?
            ↑             ↑
          master      stash{0}
          (HEAD)
```

#### 3.1.2 Индексированные и нет

Эта команда отменяет все индексированные и неиндексированные изменения в рабочей области, сохраняя их в карман (stash).

```
git stash save
```

Конечное состояние:

```
           (wt)
           (i)           
A - B - C - D             ?
            ↑             ↑
          master      stash{0}
          (HEAD)
```

> **Восстановление несохраненных изменений**: легко и просто.

```
git stash apply
```

Если stash совсем не нужен, его можно удалить.

```
# удалить последнюю запись кармана
git stash drop
```

[Подробнее про использование stash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/153503/181472).

После этого восстановить изменения всё ещё можно, но сложнее: [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89332/2790048)

### 3.2 Опасный способ

> **Осторожно!** Эта команда **безвозвратно удаляет несохраненные текущие изменения из рабочей области и из индекса** Если они вам все-таки нужны, воспользуйтесь [`git stash`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-stash/info).
>
> **Восстановление несохраненных изменений**: неиндексированные потеряны полностью, но [вы можете восстановить то, что было проиндексировано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424384/181472).

Здесь мы будем использовать [`git reset --hard`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-reset/info)

Выполняем:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Конечное состояние:

```
           (wt)
           (i)
A - B - C - D - х - х
            ↑
          master
          (HEAD)
```

## 4. Перейти к более раннему коммиту в текущей ветке и удалить из нее все последующие (неопубликованные)

> **Осторожно!** Эта команда переписывает историю Git-репозитория. **Если вы уже опубликовали ([`git push`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-push/info)) свои изменения, то этот способ использовать нельзя (см. [почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429512/))**. Используйте вариант из пункта 5 ([`git revert`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-revert/info)).

### 4.1 При этом сохранить изменения в индекс репозитория:

```
git reset --soft bbbbbb
```

После этого индекс репозитория будет содержать все изменения от `cccccc` до `dddddd`. Теперь вы можете сделать новый коммит (или несколько) на основе этих изменений.

```
           (wt)
           (i)
A - B - C - D 
    ↑
  master
  (HEAD)
```

### 4.2 Сохранить изменения в рабочей области, но не в индексе.

```
git reset bbbbbb
```

Эта команда просто перемещает указатель ветки, но не отражает изменения в индексе (он будет пустым).

```
   (i)     (wt)
A - B - C - D 
    ↑
  master
  (HEAD)
```

### 4.3 Просто выбросить изменения.

> **Осторожно!** Эта команда **безвозвратно удаляет несохраненные текущие изменения**. Если удаляемые коммиты не принадлежат никакой другой ветке, то они тоже будут потеряны.
>
> **Восстановление коммитов**: Используйте [`git reflog`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-reflog/info) и [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232455/) чтобы найти и восстановить коммиты; иначе сборщик мусора удалит их безвозвратно через некоторое время.
>
> **Восстановление несохраненных изменений**: неиндексированные потеряны полностью, но [вы можете восстановить то, что было проиндексировано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424384/181472).

Начальное состояние:

```
               (i) (wt)
A - B - C - D - ? -  ?
            ↑
          master
          (HEAD)
```

Выполняем:

```
git reset --hard bbbbbb
```

Конечное состояние:

```
   (wt)
   (i)
A - B - C - D - х - х
    ↑
  master
  (HEAD)
```

## 5. Отменить уже опубликованные коммиты с помощью новых коммитов

Воспользуйтесь командой [`git revert`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-revert/info). Она создает новые коммиты, по одному на каждый отменяемый коммит. Таким образом, если нужно отменить все коммиты после `aaaaaa`:

```
# можно перечислить отменяемые коммиты
git revert bbbbbb cccccc dddddd

# можно задать диапазон от более раннего к более позднему (новому)
git revert bbbbbb..dddddd

# либо в относительных ссылках
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD

# можно отменить коммит слияния, указывая явным образом номер предка (в нашем примере таких нет):
git revert -m 1 abcdef

# после этого подтвердите изменения:
git commit -m'детальное описание, что и почему сделано'
```

> **Восстановление**: Если revert-коммит оказался ошибочным, [используйте этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433111/181472).

Comment: Крутой ответ! Ещё бывает полезно использовать *git worktree* вместо *stash*.

Comment: todo: добавить параграф про `git worktree`.

Comment: А где чери пик ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei а как он относится к откатыванию?

Answer (score 0):

**Откат изменений в удаленном репозитарии**

Например в main попали кривые коммиты, и мы их запушили в удаленный main.
Сначала перемещаем указатель на последний стабильный коммит (до того как все пошло не так) по его хешу

```
git reset --hard mnf3m
```

и пушим в удаленный репозитарий (для защищенной ветки main должны быть включены --force пуши иначе пуш не пройдет! Это настройках ветки устанавливается.)

```
git push --force origin main
```