# Повторное слияние веток GIT

Tags: git, git-merge

Допустим я сделал слияние мастера в рабочую ветку,и решил удалить все функции и слить еще раз в нее мастер,почему при повтором слиянии функции которые есть в мастере не переносятся в рабочую ветку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Почему повторное слияние не восстанавливает изменения

Ветки до слияния:

```
master: A — B — C — D — E
             \
dev:          P — Q — R
```

Производим слияние `master` в `dev` (что немного странно, чаще в обратном направлении делают слияние).

```
master: A — B — C — D — E
             \           \
dev:          P — Q — R — Merge
```

- Слияние создает новый коммит, такой что его *предками являются два последних коммита* каждой из сливаемых веток.
- Сам коммит слияния (merge commit) становится новым последним коммитом той ветки, в которую происходит слияние.
- Та ветка, которую сливают в другую, остается нетронутой.

> **решил удалить все функции**

**Если вы сохранили эти изменения в коммит(ы)**, то получается такая структура:

```
master: A — B — C — D — E
             \           \
dev:          P — Q — R — Merge — S
```

Пытаемся снова слить master в dev: ничего нового не происходит. Последний коммит **E** ветки **master** уже является прямым предком последнего коммита **S** ветки **dev**. Требуемый результат слияния уже присутствует, слияние не требуется.

**Если вы еще не сохранили эти изменения в коммит**, то с точки зрения Git вообще ничего не изменилось. Вы повторно выполняете слияние той же ветки в ту же ветку.

До и после.

```
master: A — B — C — D — E
             \           \
dev:          P — Q — R — Merge — (stage) — (working_area)
```

Comment: Спасибо с этим моментом разобрался

Comment: @quaresma89: про откаты изменений есть тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472