# Ошибка "Unable to revert commit. Resolve the conflicts in your working directory..."

Tags: git, github, git-revert

Можно ли откатиться к любому коммиту в истории? У меня получается откатиться только к предыдущему коммиту.

При попытке откатиться к более раннему коммиту, выдает ошибку:

> Unable to revert commit. Resolve the conflicts in your working
>   directory and commit them before trying the revert again.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 3):

Revert - это не откат к коммиту. Это создание нового коммита, который содержит обратные изменения. Вам нужен или checkout, или reset, в зависимости от того, хотите вы просто переключить рабочую версию на конкретный коммит, или вообще хотите выбросить всю историю после конкретного коммита.

Answer (score -1):

Как уже сказал PashaPash, `git revert` это немного не то, что вы ожидаете.

Эта команда вносит изменения в файлы проекта, а потом вы эти изменения включаете в коммит. После коммита рабочая область проекта будет выглядеть точно так же, как при каком-то прошлом коммите. Логично, что перед тем, как вносить изменения, Git требует начать «с чистого листа», то есть зафиксировать (сделать `git commit`) или отменить все изменения. Именно об этом и повествует сообщение, выдаваемое при ошибке `revert`'a.