# Убрать последний git-коммит, не меняя файлов проекта

Tags: git

У меня есть локальный репозиторий моего проекта. Там есть несколько коммитов. Последний коммит был сделан необдуманно (вспомнилось, что там есть пара проблем, которые не хотелось бы увековечивать). Я умею возвращаться к предыдущему коммиту (команда Revert). Но это не то, что мне нужно. Так я потеряю много полезного, сделанного между предыдущим коммитом и последним(необдуманным).

В общем, хочу сделать так, чтобы последнего коммита не было, но все мои файлы были такими, какие они есть сейчас.

Comment: Здесь есть то, что вам нужно? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472

Comment: Вопрос и ответ синхронно идут )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Убрать последний коммит

#### console

Просто удаляем последний коммит из ветки, в которой находимся. Указатель ветки перейдет на предыдущий. Все изменения, внесённые в этом коммите, останутся в рабочей области проекта (т.е. в файлах на диске).

```
git reset HEAD^
```

То же самое, плюс все изменения последнего коммита будут добавлены в индекс. Можно сразу сделать из них новый коммит.

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

#### GUI

То же самое можно сделать в Android Studio: <kbd>View</kbd> → <kbd>Tool Windows</kbd> → <kbd>Version Control</kbd>, вкладка <kbd>Log</kbd>, там ПКМ по предыдущему коммиту и <kbd>Reset Current Branch to Here</kbd> (выбрать Soft)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Отредактировать (пересоздать) последний коммит

> Последний коммит был сделан необдуманно (вспомнилось, что там есть пара проблем, которые не хотелось бы увековечивать)

Этот коммит также можно <s>отредактировать</s> заменить новым. Просто добавьте в индекс все нужные файлы в том состоянии, которое достойно отлития в бронзе и высечения в мраморе.

```
git add file1 file2 folder
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Ключ `--amend` сообщает git о том, что нужно не создавать новый коммит, а пересобрать последний. Это нельзя назвать редактированием, т.к. коммиты - неизменяемые (immutable) объекты, как строки в Java.

Ключ  `--no-edit` сообщает git о том, что мы не хотим менять комментарий последнего коммита. Вместо него можно задать новый комментарий: `git commit --amend -m'bla bla bla'`

Для этого тоже есть графический способ: специальная галочка в окне создания коммита:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть git reset HEAD^ точно не испортит текущее состояние моих файлов?

Comment: @iramm не испортит, но на всякий случай вы всегда можете их забэкапить. Варианты: 1) сделать коммит в новой ветке 2) `git stash`

Comment: @iramm если что, можно редактировать не только последний коммит, просто это чуть сложнее.

Comment: Большое-большое-большое спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Изменение последнего коммита

```
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git add forgotten_file
$ git commit --amend
```

Все три команды вместе дают один коммит — второй коммит заменяет результат первого.