# Восстановление файлов из .git

Tags: git

По неопытности сделал `git reset --hard HEAD~2` , когда было всего 2 коммита(не было ни одного pushа к тому времени, только файлы в локальной репе), не знал, что это целиком захватывает файлы:(, в результате получил пустую директорию с .git (600мб), можно ли восстановить файлы?!, если да, то как?Или как-нибудь вернуться на 1 коммит после? Сроки горят, очень нужно! Не доверяйте этой статье! https://habrahabr.ru/post/138590/

Comment: `<наглая реклама>` можно доверять вот этой статье: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83) `</наглая реклама>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

да, скорее всего можно. Выполните команду `git reflog` - это лог Вашей локальной работы. Там Вы как раз увидите свои sha хеши коммитов. Теперь можно попробовать сделать `git checkout <shaхеш>` - то есть где то так `git checkout ab1cd3`. Если Вам повезет, то сорцы будут восстановлены. А дальше от этого можно сделать новую ветку (`git branch recovery`) и работать как обычно.

Comment: кланяюсь в ноги, целую, не знаю как отблагодарить!!! СПАСИБО!!! Вы спасли мой отпуск!)

Comment: на будущее - если начитались умных статей и решили поэкспериментировать с репозиторием, вначале создайте ветку для "восстановления"  - `git branch savepoint` (имя бранча может быть любое, но делать нужно в той ветке (или ветках, но тогда имя "savepoint" должны быть разные), которую будете модифицировать. В этом случае всегда можно будет откатиться (ну почти всегда).

Comment: обычно так и делал, но тут забыл, мало спал, еще раз спасибо!