# Git откатить rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Такая ситуация, что вместо merge сделал rebase. Получается изменения коряво слились, как можно откатиться к моему локальному коммиту, до того как был сделан rebase и коммит ?

Comment: @PavelMayorov эх, а я не заметил, что уже был такой вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin раз уж вы написали ответ - лучше *тот* вопрос закрыть как дубликат этого. Потому что у того вопроса низкое качество (две проблемы в одном вопросе, решена только вторая), автор убежал...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, разумное предложение, перезакрыл в обратную сторону. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ищите в рефлоге прошлый HEAD-коммит ветки, которую нужно восстановить к прошлому состоянию:

```
$ git reflog 
# это просто пример, у вас будут другие id и строки
91e9b6e HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
91e9b6e HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout @{-1}
a26257f HEAD@{2}: checkout: ...
91e9b6e HEAD@{3}: commit: ...
...
```

Просто ищите коммит с тем сообщением, которое вам нужно. Он будет третьим в списке, если вы больше ничего не делали после ребейза.

На всякий случай сделаем бэкап

```
git branch backup
```

Потом восстановим  текущую ветку к найденному коммиту. Можно использовать как id, так и указатель `HEAD@{номер}`

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
```

Если всё прошло удачно, можно удалять бэкап

```
git branch -D backup
```

Подробнее о `git reset --hard`: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83/431521#431521)

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу выше. Чтобы не использовать `git-reflog` и не копировать хэши, поможет команда с откатом по времени, например:

```
git reset --hard master@{"10 minutes ago"}
```

или

```
git reset --hard master@{12:30}
```

также должны [поддерживаться](http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html) такие варианты:

`{yesterday}, {1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}, {1979-02-26 18:30:00}`

Если Вы примерно знаете, когда совершили лишнее действие, то можете откатиться с помощью данной команды.