# GIT Как удалить ненужные коммиты без создания промежуточного `branch` a?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-reset

Как решить следующую проблему Без создания промежуточного `branch` a ?

Я перешел на мастер и сделал

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all
git merge origin master
git merge origin another_branch
```

и в `another_branch` обнаружил 3-й коммит мне ненужен.
Но все уже на `master` е.как мне удалить например 3 и 5 ый коммит чтоб не повредить остальные ?.

1) То Есть как сделать `push` без них ?

2) И если `push` уже был произведен , как исправить ситуацию ?

Пожалуйста напишите шаги по которым можно это реализовать.

Comment: Что такое третий и пятый коммиты? Покажите что у вас получилось (например `git log --online --graph`)

Comment: @Alexey Ten   commit 1,commit 2,commit 3,commit 4,commit 5,commit 6

Comment: Это значит что? Добавьте информацию в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

**git reset** - если не было отправлено на сервер, это удалит коммит

**git revert** - если было отправлено на сервер, это создаст еще один коммит который будет противоположен предыдущему (отменит все изменения)

[источник(подробней)](http://evtuhovich.ru/blog/2009/04/03/git-reset/)

Comment: Я знаю про них.но мне нужно udalit не последний и первый,а из середины

Comment: @Sergey , от не нужного коммита делаете ветку и сливаете ее с основной , так ваши изменения (ненужные) окажутся на самом верху, не уверен в этом, сам еще это не проверял

Comment: Я новичок в этом ,пожалуйста напишите рабочий `step` чтоб такие как я могли пользоваться им.

Comment: @Sergey , если честно я сам с гитом не так давно знаком, но логичней было бы вам предложить найти вводную часть в Гит, чем вводить вас в заблуждение.

Comment: Так не надо было отвечать :).подождем пока кто нибудь знающий ответит

Comment: @Sergey конечно пождем . если я не прав то удалю ответ .

Comment: Вы не правы потому что если просто удалить коммит то удаляться все коммиты после него.Тут какая то хитрая комбинация нужна

Comment: @Sergey . вы наверно думаете что коммит это копия ваших файлов? нет это не так, коммит это разница между измененными файлами. если удалить промежуточный коммит то гит вычислит разницу между крайними коммитами.