# Вернуть незакомитенные изменения

Tags: git, git-reset

Как быть, если были изменения, но я их не закомиттил. И решил удалить последние 2 коммита командой `git reset --hard HEAD~2`. Можно ли как-то вернуть файлы, которые были до `git reset`?

Comment: А `git add` делали?

Comment: к сожалению, нет

Comment: Тогда есть только шанс найти их во временных файлах текстового редактора или среды разработки. А вот два последних коммита восстановить можно, заглянув в `git reflog`. В будущем, чтобы не терять просто так несохранённые изменения, удаляйте их только с помощью `git stash`, подробности в вопросе по ссылке выше и вот в этом: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520)

Comment: О боже мой, спасибо. История изменений есть в редакторе

Comment: Хороший редактор попался )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Средствами самого git нельзя. --hard изменяет рабочую копию.