# Как удалить git commit через pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

Через pycharm сделал коммит, понял, что случайно зацепил в коммит файл, которого не должно быть в коммите.

Попробовал исправить, создал еще пару новых коммитов.

Теперь хочу удалить все лишние коммиты, как это сделать через pycharm не используя консоль?

Коммиты еще не отправлены на сервер. Использую PyCharm 2016.3.1 и Debian 8

Comment: Воспользоваться консолью...

Comment: @Qwertiy если без консоли никак, то так и сделаю. Пишу `git hist` и выводит `git: 'hist' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @EmptyMan правильно, нет такой команды. Алиас может быть )

Comment: git rebase -i и в гугл.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не понимаю.

Comment: @EmptyMan вы можете настроить короткие «ярлыки» для сложных команд git,  это называется alias или псевдоним. Например, так: `git config --global alias.lg log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow ul)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --all
`

Comment: А потом вместо этой сложной команды пишете просто `git lg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Попробовал исправить, создал еще пару новых коммитов

Вы же разработчик, используйте консоль. Это интерпретатор языка программирования Bash. По мощности и функциональности превосходит GUI настолько же, насколько программирование клавиатурой превосходит программирование мышкой.

1. Найдите тот коммит, к которому нужно возвращаться (в котором был ненужный файл задет). Вам поможет

   ```
   git log
   ```

   Посмотрите, какой коммит был **перед** этим. В логе нужно найти *sha-1* этого предыдущего коммита. Выглядит как много букв и цифр, вроде `a1ds23fef6rde...`. Скопируйте в буфер или просто запомните первые несколько символов, их будет достаточно.
2. Теперь мы вернём ветку **к предыдущему коммиту**.

   ```
   git reset --soft a1ds23^
   ```

   Теперь ваша ветка переставлена обратно на тот коммит, который был до инцидента. А в индексе уже добавлены все изменения из последующих коммитов.
3. «Забудьте» те изменения, которые не нужно включать в коммит с помощью

   ```
   git reset path/to/file
   ```

   Обратите внимание, в этот раз `reset` без параметра `--soft`!
4. Теперь можно делать новый коммит.

   ```
   git commit
   ```
5. Если оставшиеся изменения нужны, но ещё не готовы — просто продолжайте работу. 
   Если же их нужно удалить, можно использовать эту команду:

   ```
   # ОСТОРОЖНО, это удаляет несохранённые изменения
   git reset --hard
   ```

Comment: Как-то сложно всё это. @Qwertiy по-моему дельный совет дал насчёт `git rebase -i`.

Comment: @Oandriy может и сложно, но это готовое решение - бери и используй. А @Qwertiy дал совет. Если Вы можете сделать полноценный ответ по `git rebase -i` это будет достойной альтернативой имеющемуся ответу.

Comment: @EmptyMan rebase -i описан вот в этом вопросе, рекомендую прочитать. [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 2020.1, Windows 10

VCS - Git - Show history

В контекстном меню коммита "Undo Commit..."

Answer (score 0):

в PyCharm внизу выбираешь 9:Git => Вкладка Log => нажимаешь на комит правой клавишей и выбираешь Undo commit => Ok