# Как откатиться к прошлому коммиту в Android Studio, не используя командную строку?

Tags: android, android-studio, git, github

Можно ли это сделать так же как revert, одной кнопкой? Или только через командную строку? И чтобы все изменения после коммита удалились.

Comment: Ответ на [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472) рассказывает о разных способах отката, в том числе о `revert`. Все примеры там даны с использованием командной строки, но даже вы решите вместо нее использовать графический интерфейс, вы сможете использовать его правильно.

Comment: Однако я рекомендую вам попробовать командную строку, она хороша в умелых руках программиста. Alt +F9 открывает консоль.