# Git: как "раскоммитить" последний коммит

Tags: git

Ситуация:

Работал над задачей А, но появляется срочная задача В, которая не может ждать ни минуты. И получается:

1) Для сохранения промежуточных изменений я делаю `commit` в ветке А

2) Переключаюсь на ветку В, фиксю баги, пушу

3) Возвращаюсь на ветку А и хочу, чтоб все изменения, которые я второпях закоммитил, стали снова `modified` (чтоб в IDE сразу видеть, над какими файлами работал)

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Надо не коммитить, а прятать в черновики/заначки (stash)

Comment: А вообще вроде [пункты 4.1 и 4.2 в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521) вроде отвечают на ваш вопрос

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5
здесь описано ровно то, что вам нужно, без коммитов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Положить файлы в карман:

```
git stash
```

После этого можно переключаться на другую ветку, работать.

После того, как вам нужно вернуть файлы на место даёте команду

```
git stash apply
```

Другие полезные команды при работе с карманом:

```
git stash list
```

и

```
git stash drop
```

PS Но если всё-таки вдруг ну ОЧЕНЬ ХОЧЕТСЯ раскоммитить последний коммит, то есть замечательная команда:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

Comment: Еще есть такая штука как `git worktree`...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Стыдно сказать, но я знаю о ней только в теории: она появилась только в git 2 с чем-то, а у меня на машинах такое старьё стоит...

Comment: Но с `git reset HEAD~` есть нюанс, о котором надо не забывать, что для "изменений" это выход (если очень хочется), но для новых файлов - не выход, так как они будут в секции `Untracked files`, а не `new file`

Comment: @Ivan Верно, но в ситуации топикстартера сработает — когда он сначала делает `git add -A && git commit -m "temp"`