# Как подгрузить файлы которые были в gitignore?

Tags: php, git, gitignore

Здравствуйте!
Добавил файлы в `.gitignore` (не подумал, что их не будет на сервере).
Теперь понял что их нет, а они мне нужны.
Как можно их вернуть в нынешний коммит?

Comment: Зачем откатываться назад, просто внесите правки в .gitignore и сделайте новый коммит.

Comment: Сделал так, но их нет. Вернулся еще к коммиту где я их вносил в игнор, изменил там файл и слил с мастер , кое какие появились, но не все

Comment: Если так, то почитайте тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83/431521#431521

Comment: Вообще-то добавление в гитигнор не приводит к их удалению. Оно приводит к **недобавлению**. В нынешний коммит никак не добавить, коммит отпечатан его содержимым. Если изменить содержимое, это будет уже новый коммит.

Comment: Сделал так, возможно и не правильно.
вернулся к коммиту с нужными файлами, скопировал файлы в временную папку, вернулся на мастер и закачал файлы без замены.

Comment: @Hlud09 не забудьте в .gitignore эти файлы убрать

Answer (score 2):

Вы что-то спросили, не дождавшись ответа что-то сделали, потом уточнили, но всё же. Давайте всё же дадим формальный ответ на вопрос, чтобы не по комментариям было рассыпано.

Первая ремарка касается того, что нельзя добавить файлы в текущий коммит. Git устроен таким образом, что в любом месте земного шара добавляя один и тот же файл – вы получите один и тот же ID для этого файла. А коммит с чуть иным набором файлов уже будет иметь другой SHA ID.

Поэтому технически вы можете создать ещё один коммит, а потом объединить его с предыдущим – и выглядеть будет как "файлы добавлены в тот же коммит", но технически это уже будет другой коммит, с другим идентификатором.

Второй момент, который подчеркнули в комментариях – это то, что .gitignore фильтрует файлы при попытке добавления в коммит (даже если вы ещё не закоммитили сам .gitignore – он уже работает по-новому), но он никак не меняет уже созданные коммиты.

Поэтому если у вас в 2016 году был создан файл .gitignore в котором была принята политика "не добавлять папку /uploads" то вы можете весь год делать коммиты – и гит не будет замечать изменения в этой папке, фильтровать их.
А как только вы в 2017 году примете в компании новую политику "добавлять папку upload" – то вам нужно поменять .gitignore и как только вы это сделаете – то сможете в последующих коммитах добавлять файлы из этой папки.

И в предыдущих коммитах лучше уже ничего не менять, переписывание истории – это большие потери производительности людей.

Если же вы только недавно приняли для себя решение о том, что определённые файлы вам не нужны, не успели ещё запушить – то можно аккуратно переписать локальную историю как угодно, в том числе и убрать неправильные строки в .gitignore, от которых вы уже успели отказаться.