# Как отменить все изменения на ветке в Git?

Tags: git

Возникла ситуация, что мне необходимо откатить все изменения на ветке к моменту её создания, т.е. к моменту, когда была выполнена команда:

```
git checkout -B <имя_ветки>
```

Возможно ли это? Как это сделать?

UPD01. Цель откатится именно к тому состоянию, когда git начал понимать, что появилась новая ветка. Нет возможности пересоздать ветку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: Т.е. при создании ветки так же создаётся коммит? В таком случае как узнать какой был первым?

Comment: *"Т.е. при создании ветки так же создаётся коммит?"* Нет, необязательно. Ветка всегда указывает на коммит. Несколько веток вполне могут указывать на один. Нет, информации о том, откуда ветка **началась**, git не хранит, только где заканчивается.

Comment: @D-side но откуда ветка началась все таки можно отследить. Например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407526/git-how-to-find-first-commit-of-specific-branch

Comment: @lazyproger это для случая, когда известно, **от чего** было ответвление. В общем случае это не сработает, но на практике обычно хватает.

Comment: `git log --graph` найти hash коммита где была создана ветка, `git revert #hash`

Comment: @D-side вообще если честно странная задача у автора, обычно хватает просто уйти с ветки и забыть про неё, но у автора походу слишком специфичная задача

Comment: Ветка запушена на сервер или мы говорим про локальное создание ветки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

термин «ветка» («branch») — явно неудачный (в контексте сущностей, которыми манипулирует программа *git*).

ведь под словом «ветка» мы обычно подразумеваем нечто, имеющее «начало»/«основание», (как минимум один) «конец» и «что-то между ними».

в программе же *git* сущность, обозначаемая этим термином, представляет собой всего лишь **указатель** на один-единственный коммит.

эти указатели вы можете (почти) произвольно создавать:

```
$ git branch имя-нового-указателя куда-будет-указывать
```

удалять:

```
$ git branch -d имя-существующего-указателя
```

и перемещать:

```
$ git branch -f имя-существующего-указателя куда-будет-указывать
```

эти действия (понятно, кроме удаления) программа *git* фиксирует внутри хранилища в файле `logs/refs/heads/имя-указателя`. пример такого файла:

```
$ cat .git/logs/refs/heads/new 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 3d1a162a716b9ea2a91026912cf1162bf30e348d автор <автор@компьютер> 1519736572 +0300  branch: Created from HEAD
```

`3d1a1...` — это хэш коммита, на который указывал в момент создания указатель («ветка», «branch») по имени `new`.

---

если указатель («ветку», «branch») создавали именно вы в своей локальной копии хранилища, и не выполняли (пока) «сборку мусора» (`$ git gc`), то запись, озаглавленная подобным текстом (`branch: Created from`) будет в упомянутом файле присутствовать (самой первой). тогда вы сможете переключить указатель на упомянутый в записи коммит:

```
$ git branch -f ваш-указатель хэш-коммита
```

если же такой записи не найдёте, то для поиска нужного коммита можно просмотреть всё «дерево» коммитов примерно такой командой:

```
$ git log --all --graph --decorate
```