# Как восстановить файлы из предыдущего коммита(3 комита назад) в пхпшторм?

Tags: git, phpstorm

Как восстановить файлы из предыдущего коммита ( 3 коммита назад) в пхпшторм, причем файлы следующих коммитов не должны затереться.... 4 коммитом назад.

Comment: Возможно, дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: @AK, ну какой же это дубликат? вопрос о графическом интерфейсе программы phpstorm (там, вероятно, есть какие-то рудименты для скрытого от пользователя запуска программы git). про неё (phpstorm) по ссылке нет ни слова.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вопрос сформулирован весьма расплывчато, так что я решил, что автору важнее будет упор не на гуй/консоль, а на софт/хард ресет. А то можно так откатиться, что потом будет ещё один вопрос "откатился и потерял все файлы". Лучше пусть будет закрыт на дубликат, чем закрыт как "неясна суть вопроса", а если вдруг автор уточнит (чёт за сутки никакого движения) - то всегда можно и переоткрыть.