# Убрать незакомиченные изменения

Tags: git

Возможно кто-то сочтет возможным дубликатом [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83) , но я не понял ничего из ответа этого самого вопроса.

Утром поработав, никаких манипуляций с `git` не делал.

Как мне сейчас убрать все изменения и вернуться к последнему коммиту?

Приводить примеры попыток не к чему, пробовал многое и читал многое, но так и не понял...

Comment: Гугли git revert. Если уже запушил изменения, то можно вернуться назад, но тогда придется делать git push --force, а это не всегда круто.

Comment: @VostokSisters  - git revert — отмена изменений, произведенных в прошлом отдельным коммитом.

Comment: @VostokSisters, это я уже читал, но я ничего не коммитил...

Comment: а если удалить локальную ветку и заново checkout ?)

Comment: `get reset --hard`

Comment: @VTT, благодарю... Или был невнимателен или не встречал этой конкретной команды...  Может все же `git`, а не `get`... Еще раз Благодарю... Кстати оформи ответ....

Comment: Если не принципиален откат назад, а просто надо идти далее, тогда `git stash`

Comment: @L.F.C., не тот случай... Принципиален...

Comment: Понял :))))))))

Comment: Так вы к чему откатиться хотите, к тому коммиту что сделали вчера вечером или к тому, что перед ним ? Если к тому, что самый самый последний (вчера вечером который) и откатываете соответственно рабочие некоммиченные файлы - то git checkout. Если же откатить сам коммит, то git revert. А если временно вернутся к точке какого коммита то git checkout id-коммита

Comment: @Mike, VTT, уже ответил на вопрос. Я просто хотел убрать все изменения сделанные после последнего коммита...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

привести состояние рабочей копии хранилища к последнему коммиту в текущей ветке можно, например, командой:

```
$ git reset --hard
```