# Git, как коммиты из ветки A могут оказаться в списке изменения ветки B при ее слиянии с веткой C

Tags: git, git-merge

Предположим, что существует три ветки:

```
master:     a - b
feature_1:        - c - d
feature_2:        - e - f
```

Сперва происходит быстрая перемотка:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature_1
git branch -D feature_1
```

В результате чего ветки принимают следующий вид:

```
master:     a - b - c - d
feature_2:        - e - f
```

Затем происходит слияние:

```
git checkout feature_2
git merge master
```

Моя проблема заключается вот в чем: каким-то образом после слияния `master` и `feature_2` в список изменений ветки `feature_2` попали коммиты из ветки `feature_1`.

Не понимаю, как такое могло произойти.

Я предположил, что это как-то связано со стратегией слияния. Подскажите, может ли стратегия слияния стать причиной такой ситуации?

Вообще, реальная ситуация намного сложнее, потому что между началом ветки `feature_2` и моментом ее слияния с `master` произошло несколько слияний других веток. Но суть та же - в список изменений ветки попадают коммиты, которые ей не принадлежат.

Comment: Вы слились с веткой `feature1`. А теперь не хотите? Тогда вернитесь назад. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/Как-вернуться-откатиться-к-более-раннему-коммиту

Comment: @AlexGlebe, нет, я имею в виду другое. Почему в изменениях ветки `feature_2` присутствуют коммиты, которые относятся не к этой ветке?

Comment: Мне кажется так не бывает. Пригодился бы [mcve] с выводом `git log --graph --oneline --all` на каждом шаге.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, мне тоже кажется, что так не бывает. Поэтому, я бы хотел найти минимальный воспроизводимый пример, но пока не нашел.

Comment: Такое могло произойти если сделали `get rebase`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вряд ли.

Comment: Так вы же сами слили их туда: *feature 1* -> *master* -> *feature 2*. Это не стратегия слияния, это ваши шаги привели к такому. Не понимаю в чём вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

ветка в программе *git* — это (плавающий) указатель на коммит.

при выполнении команды *merge* передвигается **текущий** указатель, а не тот, который указан параметром команде.

---

вот такое дерево коммитов у вас было (перед последней вашей операцией):

```
a - b - c - d
      \ e - f
```

указатель `master` указывал на коммит `d`, а указатель `feature_2` указывал на коммит `f`.

перед слиянием можно было сделать текущим указатель `master` (и параметром команды — `feature_2`), а можно было `feature_2` (и параметром команды — `master`). в обоих случаях в результате получилось бы такое дерево (здесь `g` — это «коммит слияния»):

```
a - b - c - d - g
      \ e - f /
```

но в первом случае переместился бы указатель `master`, и стал бы указывать на коммит `g` (указатель `feature_2` так бы и продолжил указывать на `f`), а во втором случае переместился бы указатель `feature_2`, и стал бы указывать на `g` (указатель `master` так бы и продолжил указывать на `d`).

вы пошли по второму пути (сделали текущим `feature_2` и параметром команде *merge* указали `master`), но, судя по вашему недоумению, вам надо было пойти по первому (сделать текущим `master` и параметром команде *merge* указать `feature_2`).