# Запушил напрямую в мастер

Tags: git

У меня есть ветка task-2 в которой я вносил изменения, когда я внёс изменения я сделал коммит и случайно запушил напрямую в мастер на github, а нужно было запушить task-2 так чтобы открыть pull request, как исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой командой вы пушили ?
Если вы пушите командой

```
git push origin task-2
```

То у вас по идее создастся ветка task-2 в репозитории, отдельно от ветки мастер
Если вы пушили этой командой:

```
git push origin
```

То запушится ветка, на которой стоял указатель HEAD, то есть, если вы находились на task - 2, то все пройдет ровно так же как и в первом случае.
Git не позволит запушить вам ветку task-2 на ветку master, только смержить.
Если вы все таки мержили ветку task-2, то на локальном репозитории выполните команду:

```
git merge --abort
```

Она вернет состояние до мержа.
Если я вас понял не так, как нужно вы всегда можете посмотреть историю коммитов на локальном репозитории командой:

```
git log
```

Перейти на коммит без слияния/пуша на мастер-ветку командой:

```
git checkout (hash коммита)
```

Далее запушить состояние вашей мастер-ветки на удаленный репозиторий:

```
git push origin master
```